# Git not pulling all files but checking out a branch has them?

Tags: git, github, merge

So I'm in branch A. I do `git pull origin master` and it tells me I'm up to date. I checkout master and I see File 1. I checkout branch A and File 1 is not there even though it tells me I'm up to date.

I checkout master again, create branch B. I checkout branch B and File 1 is there. I do git pull origin A and File 1 is no longer there. Same happens if I reverse the process and create B then push to B from A. So at this point I can't push to master because it appears I will delete much needed files but I can't pull and get them.

I have changes in branch A I want and I haven't deleted any files. For some reason it's acting like I deleted File 1 and even if I deleted it accidentally, why wouldn't a pull return it for me?

Is there a way I can tell git to give me all missing files from one branch to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, it sounds like you deleted File1 in branchA. When pulling from `origin/master`, Git sees that nothing happened to File1 in `origin/master`, and that the file has been deleted in branchA, so when it merges them, that merges cleanly as deleting File1. Remember, a "pull" is just a way of fetching and automatically merging two branches.

If you want to restore File1 on branchA, there are a couple of options. If you haven't pushed it yet, one option is just to rebase and get rid of the removal. Or, you can run `git checkout master -- File1` to check out the version of File1 that is present on master, and add that to a commit on branchA to add it back.

If you want to compare branches, just `git diff` should suffice. If you want to just see which files have been added, removed, or changed, you can use `git diff --stat`. Try doing `git diff --stat master origin/master` to see what has changed between your master branch and `origin/master`.

It can also be useful to visualize these changes with `gitk` or `git log --graph --decorate --oneline`. `gitk master...origin/master`, or `gitk origin/master...branchA` can help you see what commits are in one of those branches but not the other.

Comment: Ok so I left out that local master is up to date with origin master. In master, I also do a git pull origin master just fine and it has File 1.

Comment: @o_O Ah, looks like I misinterpreted what you wrote. I have updated my answer based on a closer reading.

Comment: Yeah I'm sol. I tried rebasing already and it does a lot of stuff that's beyond my level. I was really hoping there was just a simple way to get the files back.

Comment: It does seem strange there is no command to just add all files from remote branch to current branch that are not present.

Comment: There is.  `git checkout origin/master -- $(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A @ origin/master)` to retrieve `origin/master` files missing in your current checkout.

Answer (score 0):

One of your commits in branch A deletes the file (or files) you care about. Since you say you can't push branch A because of this, I am assuming you haven't published your history, and would like to rewrite it.

To find the commit which deletes the file, try:

```
git log --stat master..A
```

then try:

```
git checkout A
git rebase -i master
```

and mark the commit that you would like to fix for editing with 'e'.

Then use look at the state of that commit:

```
git status
```

And undo the removal of those files:

```
git reset file-that-was-deleted
git checkout -- file-that-was-deleted
```

And resume the rebase:

```
git rebase --continue
```